# ASP.NET Web API looking for web.config in the wrong spot

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

IIS 7.5 is looking for my web.config file in a mapped route and not in the actual folder location.

Example
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\api\thedoors\1 <-- is where it's looking this is not a directory but a specified url in WebApiConfig class

Where it should look is
c:\inetpub]wwwroot\thedoors\

I'm using publish from VS 2012 to publish locally to my IIS 7.5 web server.

## Server Error in Application "THEDOORS"

Internet Information Services 7.5

Error Summary

### HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

#### The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Detailed Error Information 
   
    
    ModuleIIS Web Core 
    NotificationMapRequestHandler 
    HandlerStaticFile 
    Error Code0x80070002 

    
   
   
    
    Requested URLhttp://localhost:80/api/thedoors/1 
    Physical PathC:\inetpub\wwwroot\TheDoors\api\thedoors\1 
    Logon MethodAnonymous 
    Logon UserAnonymous 

    
    
   
  
 
 
 Most likely causes:

- The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
- The URL contains a typographical error.
- A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Things you can try:

- Create the content on the Web server.
- Review the browser URL.
- Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439).

Links and More Information 
  This error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the request again.

[View more information »](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=404,0,0x80070002,7600)

Comment: Is that the error returned by the IIS? Could you post the full error?

Comment: I have now posted the error

Comment: So clearly there is an issue with iis 7.5 and not having something configured with to route request appropriately. Very angry at microsoft for making this so damn hard to deploy such a simple web api. Still don't exactly what is wrong.

Comment: The application does work if I run it Visual Studio, it's just when I actually try to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

Benny, this is not the problem with the virtual location of your web.config file. It is telling you that something about your web.config file is not correct. It seems that it cannot find physical web.config in the location `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\api\thedoors\web.config` where your Web API is executing. Do you have the file in the specified location?

UPDATE: I would open IIS Managment Console and check folder mappings.

I just created a sample Web API project and published it to a local IIS, but I cannot reproduce the issue. My folder mappings seem to be OK. The folder is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sampleapi and web.config is there.

Comment: That's my point the location it is trying to look for the file does not exist, however C:\inetpub\wwwroot\thedoors does.

It seems that is is trying to look in the location where my webapiconfig mapped route is specifying, which of course /api/ folder does not exists. Make sense?

Comment: I think it has something to do with IIS 7.5 and the way the routing is set up.